# How to make a progress bar with custom height?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, progress-bar

I want something like the following. Is there any control available like this? [image]

Comment: https://github.com/lightdesign/LDProgressView

Comment: You modify it according ur requirement

Answer (score 1):

Subclass the UIProgressView class and define your own behaviour in there.
Alternatively take a look at [Cocoa Controls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com) and see if someone has already done it, I'm sure there'll be something for you there. Make sure you take time to look at how they did it so you can learn for the next time you need a custom control.

Answer (score 1):

UIProgressView does not have `height` property or something similar, but you can use following:

```
_progressView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 10.0f);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no such native control in Xcode. You have to develop custom control.